# Unity Facebook AppRequestCallback

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm having a problem to get the users' id when after I send a app request.
In the facebook manual, it is described as 
"An array of the recipient user IDs for the request that was created."
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Apprequest
And my code in the callback is like:

    `if(responseObject.TryGetValue ("to", out to))
    {
    string[] output = (string[])to;
    print(output.Length);
    }`

Where responseObject is a deserialized FBResult.
But this is giving me and error says: 
"InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type."
I have also tried foreach string in the object, but it just would convert.
Can I please get some help on getting the number of users that I have sent request to please. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

First cast it to list of objects

```
if(responseObject.TryGetValue ("to", out to)) { 


    List<object> output = (List<object>)to; 

    print(output.Count);

    foreach(object uid in output) {
        print(uid.ToString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void RequestFriendsCallback(IGraphResult result)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.RawResult))
    {
        var resultDictionary = result.ResultDictionary;
        if (resultDictionary.ContainsKey("data"))
        {
            var dataArray = (List<object>)resultDictionary["data"];//2.1.4
            var dic = dataArray.Select(x => x as Dictionary<string, object>).ToArray();
            foreach (var item in dic)
            {
                string id = (string)item["id"];
                var url = item.Where(x => x.Key == "picture").SelectMany(x => x.Value as Dictionary<string, object>).Where(x => x.Key == "data").SelectMany(x => x.Value as Dictionary<string, object>).Where(i => i.Key == "url").First().Value;
                FriendData friend = Friends.Where(x => x.FacebookID == id).FirstOrDefault();
                if (friend != null)
                    GetPictureByURL("" + url, friend);
            }
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error))
        {
            Debug.Log(result.Error);

        }
    }
}
```